# find and replace not work with macro, does not work with general and text formatting

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I to all
The macro attached i don't understand why it doesen't find the exact value,
it work partially

If the search cells are in general format it works fine

if the cells are in text format, the value to search for is double

in the workbook there can be columns/cells with text and general format

in the attached sheet the research number and 500

column B is in text format, the others are general

the number 500 in yellow column B are double

---

note: the macro is linked to a button

insert a button in the sheet and name  = tutte le celle colonna

example as attached image:

click button "tutte le celle colonna"

click button "scegli colonna " (column) = A:E

click button "trova " (search) = 500

notice = codice trovato 18 - no exact

exact = 15

---

```
Sub sostituisci_codice_2()

    Dim VecchioValore   As Variant, _
        NuovaPparola    As Variant, _
        TrovatoSu       As Variant
        
    Dim IntervalloDiRicerca As Range
    Dim Avviso              As Variant
    Dim Col                 As String
    Dim result_1            As Double
    Dim add As String
    
    Col = Application.InputBox("inserisci la colonna:", "SCEGLI COLONNA")
    'Col = InputBox("inserisci la colonna:", "COLONNA")
    
    
    
    Select Case Col
         Case Is = ""
            Avviso = MsgBox("Devi inserire una colonna!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = UCase(False)
            Exit Sub
   End Select
   
On Error GoTo BadAdd


Set IntervalloDiRicerca = Columns(Col)

VecchioValore = Application.InputBox("codice/parola da ricercare:", "TROVA")

   
    
    Select Case VecchioValore
         Case Is = ""
            Avviso = MsgBox("Devi inserire un codice/parola!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = False
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Set TrovatoSu = IntervalloDiRicerca.Find(VecchioValore)
    
    If Not TrovatoSu Is Nothing Then
        
               
        
      result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), "*" & VecchioValore & "*")
    If IsNumeric(VecchioValore) Then
      result_1 = result_1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), VecchioValore)
    End If
    
    
        
        
        Avviso = MsgBox("trovato " & result_1 & " " & Chr(13) & _
        "< " & VecchioValore & " > " & Chr(13) & _
        "codice/parola", vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        
        NuovaPparola = Application.InputBox("nuovo codice/parola:", "SOSTITUISCI")
        If NuovaPparola = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            IntervalloDiRicerca.Replace VecchioValore, NuovaPparola, xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False
            Set IntervalloDiRicerca = Nothing
        End If

     Else
        Avviso = MsgBox("nessun codice/parola trovato!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
        'On Error Resume Next
        'quantità trovata
        'result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, TrovatoSu)
        'result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), TrovatoSu)
         
'        Avviso = MsgBox("trovato " & result_1 & " " & Chr(13) & _
'        "< " & VecchioValore & " > " & Chr(13) & _
'        "codice/parola", vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        
'     On Error GoTo 0
'
'    If Not TrovatoSu Is Nothing Then
'    Else
'        Avviso = MsgBox("nessun codice/parola trovato!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
'        Exit Sub
'    End If



Exit Sub


BadAdd:
   MsgBox "Valore non valido." & Chr(13) & _
          "Devi inserire una lettera/colonna !", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!"


End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attached sheet"?

Comment: `Find(VecchioValore)` is not enough to find what you need. `Find` function has many parameters. If you use only the `What` one, it will work according to your last search,  even if it was done manually. I mean, `LookIn:=LookIn`, or whatever you need, `LookAt:=xlWhole ` or `xlPart`, `SearchOrder`,`SearchDirection`, `MatchCase` etc. Of course, according to your real needs.

Comment: no particular need.
The macro must find both values formatted as text and values formatted as general

Comment: O.k. correct thread

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sostituisci_codice_2()

    Dim VecchioValore   As Variant, _
        NuovaPparola    As Variant, _
        TrovatoSu       As Variant
        
    Dim IntervalloDiRicerca As Range
    Dim Avviso              As Variant
    Dim Col                 As String
    Dim result_1            As Double
    Dim add As String
    
    Col = Application.InputBox("inserisci la colonna:", "SCEGLI COLONNA")
    'Col = InputBox("inserisci la colonna:", "COLONNA")
    
    
    
    Select Case Col
         Case Is = ""
            Avviso = MsgBox("Devi inserire una colonna!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = UCase(False)
            Exit Sub
   End Select
   
On Error GoTo BadAdd


Set IntervalloDiRicerca = Columns(Col)

VecchioValore = Application.InputBox("codice/parola da ricercare:", "TROVA")

   
    
    Select Case VecchioValore
         Case Is = ""
            Avviso = MsgBox("Devi inserire un codice/parola!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
            Exit Sub
        Case Is = False
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Set TrovatoSu = IntervalloDiRicerca.Find(VecchioValore)
    
    If Not TrovatoSu Is Nothing Then
        
               
        
      result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), "*" & VecchioValore & "*")
    If IsNumeric(VecchioValore) Then
      result_1 = result_1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), VecchioValore)
    End If
    
    
        
        
        Avviso = MsgBox("trovato " & result_1 & " " & Chr(13) & _
        "< " & VecchioValore & " > " & Chr(13) & _
        "codice/parola", vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        
        NuovaPparola = Application.InputBox("nuovo codice/parola:", "SOSTITUISCI")
        If NuovaPparola = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            IntervalloDiRicerca.Replace VecchioValore, NuovaPparola, xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False
            Set IntervalloDiRicerca = Nothing
        End If

     Else
        Avviso = MsgBox("nessun codice/parola trovato!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
        'On Error Resume Next
        'quantità trovata
        'result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, TrovatoSu)
        'result_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(Col), TrovatoSu)
         
'        Avviso = MsgBox("trovato " & result_1 & " " & Chr(13) & _
'        "< " & VecchioValore & " > " & Chr(13) & _
'        "codice/parola", vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
        
'     On Error GoTo 0
'
'    If Not TrovatoSu Is Nothing Then
'    Else
'        Avviso = MsgBox("nessun codice/parola trovato!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!")
'        Exit Sub
'    End If



Exit Sub


BadAdd:
   MsgBox "Valore non valido." & Chr(13) & _
          "Devi inserire una lettera/colonna !", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "AVVISO!"


End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please, delete it, edit your question and paste the code there.

Comment: i don't know how to change the answer as soon as i enter the macro code it gives me error

Comment: You do not have to change jt. You should delete it and copy its code inside of your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image sheet1 number formatting general and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvIM.png)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting answer, the link to edit is just below your question.

Comment: the question is what i am looking for, sorry for my english